# How to determine the existence of points on a circle (with polynomials)

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Let  $P\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such as $P(a)\neq 0$. Assume that $a$ is root of order $k$ of $P-P(a)$.

Show, for $\rho>0$ small enough, there exist, on a circle centred at  $a$ and radius $\rho$,  $2k$ points  such that $|P(z)|=|P(a)|$.

I can assume that $a=0$ (by translation), and the equality: $|P(\rho e^{i\theta})|=|P(0)| $ 
can be written (with the assumption on the root):
$$P(\rho e^{i\theta})-P(0)=a_{k}\rho^{k}e^{ik\theta}(1+Q(\rho e^{i\theta})),$$
where $a_{k}$ are the coefficients of the polynomial.

But now I don't know how to continue? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please explain why you can assume that. I'm not saying it's false, but it would be nice to see the reasoning. Note that I changed "the root" to "a root", which I think makes a lot more sense. Note also that moduli/absolute values are written either `|x|` ($\TeX$ style) or `\lvert x\rvert` ($\LaTeX$ style), but never `\mid x\mid`, which gets the spacing all wrong. `\mid` is used for "divides" and sometimes in set-builder notation or with angle brackets as in $\langle a\mid b\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use argument principle: the small circle around the origin will be mapped to a curve that goes around $P(0)$ $k$ times. Now by "Jordan theorem" such curve will intersect a circle passing through $P(0)$ and centered in the origin $2k$ times.

Comment: Thanks but Jordan theorem is not in my cursus..

Comment: You can avoid using Jordan theorem by making an inversion that maps this circle to a line. Then you can apply classical argument principle

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand your answer. I must use an equation of the circle that goes around P(0) k times ? Can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: No,not the equation. Pick any point on the circle (say $b=-P(0)$) and look at the compozition of map $P$ and this inversion. The your question is How many times an image of the small circle intersect a line? but this is equivalent to How many times an argument of the $\hat{P}(z)-\hat{P}(0)$ is equal $\pm \alpha$, where $\hat{P}$ is the new map. That is exactly argument principle.